# hashing algorithm mail signing

Tags: hash, smime

What determines the hashing algorithm used form mail signing? I sign an mail. it is first run through a hashing algorithm and next encrypted with my private key. Bob, the receiver will decrypt it with the corresponding public key, but how does we/ his mail client know what hashing algorithm to run through the message to compare the hashes ?

Comment: What kind of mail signing are you talking about?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'm referring to digitally signed messages https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Send-a-digitally-signed-or-encrypted-message-a18ecf7f-a7ac-4edd-b02e-687b05eff547

Comment: Ah, so you're referring to S/MIME.